# "Algebraic indistinguishability"

Tags: terminology, galois-theory, intuition

When people talk about Galois theory they often say that the basic idea behind it is that certain numbers are "algebraicaly indistinguishable".

I never really understood what this means in a way that doesn't make any reference to the concept of field automorphism.

So is there some intuitive way of looking at this?